# Thymeleaf get current locale from request or session

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I get current locale in thymeleaf template ?

I've tried

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="${#locale}" xml:lang="${#locale}" class="no-js">
```

and

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="${request.locale}" xml:lang="${request.locale}" class="no-js">
```

but none of both works

Comment: Locale is an object - so you have to specify what attribute(s) you want - for example: `th:lang="${#locale.language}"` or `th:country="${#locale.country}"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:lang="${#locale.language}" 
      th:xmllang="${#locale.language}" 
      class="no-js">
```

There are quite a lot of attributes like these, each of them targeting a specific **[XHTML or HTML5 attribute](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes)**.

Comment: Since Java 7, I recommend using [`Locale.toLanguageTag()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#toLanguageTag()) to include the regions etc. if present (e.g. `en-CA` for Canadian English). In this case it would be `th:lang="${#locale.toLanguageTag()}" th:xmllang="${#locale.toLanguageTag()}"`